# Need suggestions for wire size, wire connection, etc. for building an autonomous mobile robot

Tags: mobile-robot, autonomous-car

I am a newbie and I want to build an autonomous mobile robot.

I am using 4 brushed DC motor (stall current 5.0A). I am using four MD20A motor drivers (20A continuous, 60A peak).

The wire coming out of the LiPo battery is 12 AWG with an XT60 connector.

I am using a fuse block to control the current flow. I will use four 5A fuse blades.

I need suggestions on whether my choices are correct. Do I need to add any more things to make it secure?

[image: Connection Diagram]

Answer (score 1):

The wire sizes are generous, the motor drivers are more than adequate.  If your motors happen to be 6 V, your control will be squished down at the low end (like 6/14.8) of the range. But no real problems there.

The only thing I wonder about is if the fuse rating is inconveniently conservative. It would be obnoxious if a momentary stall blows a fuse. At 5 A, they are basically thermal protection for the motors against overheating during a protracted stall. (Everything else could tolerate a higher current.) I'm thinking slow-blow, but I have never seen that in blade format, so I don't have a specific recommendation.

Caveat: I'm reasoning from electrical engineering here, not from specific experience...

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I understand, I will use 7.5A fuses.